# MRTK BoundsControl Meta Quest 2

Tags: mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I am Currently working with MRTK (Microsoft Mixed Reality Toolkit).
I have a doubt in MRTK can I access the built in script of MRTK in my custom script?

1. I have one MRTK script name "BoundsControl". Which contents Targeted gameObject.
2. I have created my custom script which is attached to the pointer (Cursor) in MRTK Cursor.
3. When both collides (cursor & targetObject as gameObject) I want to enable the BoundsControl Script. So I can scale, rotate that particular TargetObject.
4. I tried to getComponent but showing me an error.

This is in my custom script
// Enable the BoundsControl script on the target GameObject
GameObject targetObject = targetObject;
BoundsControl boundsControl = targetObject.GetComponent();

Could anyone of can tell me where I am going wrong.

I want to access the "BoundsControl" Script of MRTk (If accessable- I dont know whether its accessable or not please clear my doubts?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access the **BoundsControl** script from your custom script.

You’re attempting to get the **BoundsControl** component from the ***targetObject***, but you haven’t specified the type of component you’re trying to get. Here’s how you can correct it:

```
BoundsControl boundsControl = targetObject.GetComponent<BoundsControl>();
```

For more information on how to use **BoundsControl** in your code, you can refer to [Bounds control - MRTK 2 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/ux-building-blocks/bounds-control?view=mrtkunity-2022-05#how-to-add-and-configure-a-bounds-control-in-the-code).